# permissions denied for an external hard disk

Tags: permissions, mount, hard-drive, nautilus

I am new to all of this so sorry in advance! I bought an external hard disk (Maxtor M3 portable) and I already mounted it to use it with my linux. After copying the jpg images from my samsung to linux and then to the hard disk, I tried to preview them but each time I receive a message telling me *" failed: Permission denied"*.

After reading [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=789037), I used `gksudo nautilus` and it worked successfully, I was able to see the pictures.

I am looking now for a durable solution! I would like to know how can I fix my hard disk so that I can preview the images without the use of `gksudo nautilus` each time?

EDIT: Again I am sorry if this is not the right place to post my question, thanks to any advice concerning the right place. Also, I would be very happy to provide any information or to answer any question regarding my problem.

Comment: How are you mounting it in LInux? What commands did you use to copy the files to the drive? What is the output of `ls -ld /maxtor/mount/point`?

Comment: ** mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt  AND then ** sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1 ..............To copy "" sudo cp -R LocationofTheHardDisk  LocationofTheWantedFile ""

Comment: @WayneVosberg But with sudo ls -ld /maxtor/mount/point......... No such file or directory!!! What I am missing?

Comment: When you get the "permission denied", are you running the command as root (sudo)?  If it works okay as root, I suspect the files and directories are all owned by root and have insufficient permissions to allow your personal account to see them.

Comment: /maxtor/mount/point is where you mounted your drive. You can get it from `df` if you don't remember.

Comment: I see from your other response - you mounted the drive at /mnt and then copied the files using sudo. So they are all owned by root. Try `sudo chown -R <you>:<your group> /mnt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more detailed answer:

1) If you intend to leave this drive attached to the system and want it available to other users:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
$ sudo mkdir /mnt/maxtor
$ sudo echo "/dev/sdb1 /mnt/maxtor ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1" >> /etc/fstab
$ sudo mount /mnt/maxtor
$ sudo chmod 1777 /mnt/maxtor
$ sudo chown -R <you>:<your group> /mnt/maxtor/*
```

Now, any user should be able to create files on the drive but you can only delete/modify files you own.

2) If this drive is only for your use:

`$ sudo umount /mnt`

Unplug the drive and plug it back in. The drive should automagically mount at `/media/<you>/<drive name>`, and it will only be accessible by you.

Comment: following the instruction in case 2, I got *"umount: /mnt: not mounted"* !..........whereas when doing *"sudo umount -l <hard disk location> "* worked for unmounting. In contrary unmounting didn't solve the issue!

Comment: Does `df` show the drive as mounted? `umount -l` will not unmount the drive till it is no longer busy -- so it may not have actually done it yet.

Comment: Did you do `umount -l /mnt` or is /mnt not really the current mount point?

Comment: Yes it does *" /dev/sdb1  961301032  4002708 908443940   1%   /media/...."*

Comment: Since *" df"* showed the drive mounted and from this *" umount: /mnt: not mounted "* I got that it is not mounted then I think it is not the mount point!

Comment: OK - so when you unplugged and replugged it mounted in the proper place - so if you haven't updated ownership you should do it now: `sudo chown -R <you>:your group> /media/<you>/<drive>` and from now on it should be good.